# Kafka Connect S3 source throws java.io.IOException

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka Connect S3 source connector throws the following exception around 20 seconds into reading an S3 bucket:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.isReadAllowed(EofSensorInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:180)
```

The error is preceded by the following warnning:

```
WARN Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use. (com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream:178)
```

I am running Kafka connect out of this image: `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0`. Using the `confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-source-2.1.1` jar.

My source connector configuration looks like so:

```
{
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "s3.region":"eu-central-1",
    "s3.bucket.name":"test-bucket-yordan",
    "topics.dir":"test-bucket/topics",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "schema.compatibility":"NONE",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "blockchain-kafka-kafka-0.blockchain-kafka-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092",
    "transforms":"AddPrefix",
   "transforms.AddPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.AddPrefix.regex":".*",
    "transforms.AddPrefix.replacement":"$0_copy"
}
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue? Also I was unable to find the repository of Kafka connect S3 *source* connector, is it opensource?

Edit: I don't see the problem if gzip compression on the kafka-connect sink is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that `close()`was called before the file was read. S3 was not done with sending the data but the connection was left hanging.

2 options:

1. Validate that the input stream contains no more data. That way the connection can be reused
2. Call `s3ObjectInputStream.abort()` (NOTE: this connection could not be reused if you abort the input stream and a new one will need to created which will have performance impact.) In some cases this might make sense e.g. when the read is getting too slow etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not working with S3 programmatically but instead using this piece of software:
https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.0/connect/kafka-connect-s3-source
i'm trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: confluent is a commercial distribution of Kafka, isn't it? So, I would cut a support ticket to Confluent.

Comment: It was my understanding that a license is required only for running inside Confluent infrastructure, I would inquire about this further, thanks for the hint.